# How to define artifactory plugin's publications in Gradle

Tags: gradle, artifactory

I have a Gradle project, which builds a Nifi NAR file using `de.fanero.gradle.plugin.nar` plugin (https://github.com/sponiro/gradle-nar-plugin).

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://dl.bintray.com/sponiro/gradle-plugins' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'de.fanero.gradle.plugin.nar', name: 'gradle-nar-plugin', version: '0.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'de.fanero.gradle.plugin.nar'
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    ...
}
```

Now I want to upload a NAR file to a Jfrog Artifactory using `com.jfrog.artifactory` plugin. I'm struggling with publication definition. I tried to do something similar to the definition below but I failed.

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from project.components.java
        }
    }
}
```

The only way I managed to do that is to explicitly define file path, but I want to use it as the last resort.

```
nar(MavenPublication) {
    artifact file("build/libs/my-custom-nar-1.0-SNAPSHOT.nar")
}
```

I will appreciate all suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what NAR is, but I've published custom, non JAR, artifacts with a configuration like this:

1. Define your artifact. It can be a ZIP, or JAR, or TAR:

   ```
   task deployableZIP(type: Zip) {
       from 'deployable'
       baseName = 'deployable'
       destinationDir = buildDir
   }
   ```
2. Configure publishing:

   ```
   publishing {
       publications {
           main(MavenPublication) {
               artifact source: deployableZIP, extension: 'zip'
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Note that a `publications` block referres to a `deployableZIP` task itself: no quotes, just a task reference.

I believe, in your case, `nar` task is already created by a plugin, so what you have to do is:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        main(MavenPublication) {
            artifact source: nar, extension: 'nar'
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can just use that publication in [Gradle Artifactory plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin):

```
artifactory {
    contextUrl = 'http://artifacto.ry'
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-snapshot-local'
            username = 'darth_vader'
            password = 'padme'
        }
        defaults {
            publications('main')
            publishArtifacts = true
        }
    }
}
```

Dozens of examples are available [here](https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples/tree/master/gradle-examples/4).

Comment: `artifact source: nar.archivePath` is enough in my case :)

Comment: @Grzes:: Can you please provide your entire build.gradle file?